# AngularJS Digest Cycle Occasionally Fails to Update Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, ng-animate

Angular Devs!

I'm running into a bit of an issue when using ngAnimate and UI-Router together. Basically, I have five child states ("slides") that make up my main content as well as a button on each side. These buttons go to the previous and next slides respectively when clicked.

I'm using CSS3 translations to animate the entry and exit of the slides. When the user clicks the left button, the current slide exits to the right and the "previous" slide enters from the left. The opposite is true when the right button is clicked: the current slide exits to the left and the "next" slide enters from the right. These slides loop around, so slide zero goes to slide four and vice-versa.

The direction my slides enter and exit the viewport (keep in mind that the slides are UI-Router states, so they are removed from the DOM at the end of the animations) is determined by a class that I apply to the parent element. Applying the "left" class makes the slides animate left, and the reverse for the "right" class.

The code is broken up into several elements:

- appSlideDirective

  - directive that contains slide buttons and an embedded UI-Router view div (content)
  - handles user button presses and passes click events to baseController for state transitions
- baseController

  - controller that belongs to parent module, manages stateService
- stateService (only used by baseController)

  - navigates between UI-Router states when the directive sends it events
- slideService (only used by directive)

  - manages 'left' and 'right' class addition and removal (via ng-click)

**Directive HTML:**

```
<div id="slide-container">
    <div id="slide" data-ng-class="{ left: slide.getTransitionState().left, right: slide.getTransitionState().right }">
        <div id="slide-content" data-ui-view></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Relevant Directive Code:**

```
angular.module('app').directive('appSlide', function(slideService) {
restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        currentState: '=',
        numberOfStates: '=',
        loadPreviousState: '&onPreviousState',
        loadNextState: '&onNextState'
    },
    templateUrl: 'slide.html',
    link: function(scope, element) {
        scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
            element.empty();
        });
    },
    controller: function($scope, $timeout) {
        var vm = this;

        // ...

        vm.loadPreviousSlide = function() {
            slideService.preparePreviousSlide();
            $scope.loadPreviousState();
        });
        vm.loadNextSlide = function() {
            slideService.prepareNextSlide();
            $scope.loadNextState();
        });
        vm.getTransitionState = function() {
            return slideService.getTransitionState();
        };

        // ...

    },
    controllerAs: 'slide'
});
```

**Relevant Controller Code:**

```
angular.module('app').controller('baseController', function(stateService) {
    var vm = this;

    // ...

    vm.loadPreviousState = function() {
        stateService.loadPreviousState();
    };
    vm.loadNextState = function() {
        stateService.loadNextState();
    };

    // ...
});
```

**Relevant Service Code:**

```
angular.module('app').factory('slideService', function() {
    var _transitionState = {
        left: false,
        right: false
    };

    return {
        preparePreviousSlide: function() {
            _transitionState.right = false;
            _transitionState.left = true;
        },
        prepareNextSlide: function() {
            _transitionState.left = false;
            _transitionState.right = true;
        },
        getTransitionState: function() {
            return _transitionState;
        }

        // ...
    };
});

angular.module('app').factory('stateService', function($state) {

    // ...

    return {

        // ...

        loadPreviousState: function() {
            var targetState = _calculatePreviousState();
            $state.go( targetState );
        },
        loadNextState: function() {
            var targetState = _calculateNextState();
            $state.go( targetState );
        }

        // ...
    };
});
```

This works fairly well -- for the most part. The first slide transition fails to animate on page load, since neither the 'left' class nor the 'right' class are present. Similarly, switching directions (i.e. going left twice, then right once) makes the slides appear from the wrong side, since the previous animation's 'left'/'right' class is still on the element.

After some digging, I think I've stumbled onto why the first/opposite animations are failing: the ng-click event starts a digest cycle that blocks any scope changes from occurring until after all of its actions are complete -- meaning the state is changed before the proper 'left'/'right' class is and its corresponding CSS3 transform styles can be applied. So, I need to run another digest cycle once I have properly updated the 'left' and 'right' classes and only then change the state.

I went through a lot of code iterations and my current implementation relies on $scope.$apply and the $timeout service. To force another digest cycle, I run $scope.$apply -- and I use $timeout to prevent "in progress" errors. I then run my state changes when the $timeout promise is resolved.

**Relative Directive Updates**

```
vm.loadPreviousSlide = function() {
    var promise = $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            slideService.preparePreviousSlide();
        });
    }, 0, false);
    promise.then(function() {
        $scope.loadPreviousState();
    });
};
vm.loadNextSlide = function() {
    var promise = $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            slideService.prepareNextSlide();
        });
    }, 0, false);
    promise.then(function() {
        $scope.loadNextState();
    });
};
```

I have two problems with this. First, it offends my sensibilities -- it strikes me as more complicated than it needs to be. Second, it **doesn't work 100%** of the time. Sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't. I have no clue why it fails.

What do you guys think? Let me know if you come up with any better solutions or if you can figure out why mine occasionally fails! Thanks for your time.

Oh, one last thing -- I'm fairly new to AngularJS, so please feel free to give recommendations on code structure or methodology as well!

Comment: why `$scope.$apply()` wraps in `$timeout` any reason?

Comment: The initial ng-click event triggers a digest cycle, but the 'left'/'right' classes aren't ready at that point -- so I call $scope.$apply() when they are. Unfortunately, the initial digest cycle will prevent $scope.$apply() from starting a new one, so I need to implement it in a callback/promise. A $timeout with delay 0 will run as soon as the current digest cycle ends, according to the documentation. Also, I disable the $timeout apply wrapping (third parameter, false) because I couldn't get it to work otherwise.

Comment: instead of this `var promise = $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            slideService.prepareNextSlide();
        });
    }, 0, false);` try `var promise =  $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
            slideService.prepareNextSlide();
        });`

Comment: $evalAsync doesn't return a promise, so I had to keep the $timeout. I just replaced $scope.$apply with $scope.$evalAsync. It looks like it's working 100% of the time -- I'll post back after more testing. I can't help but wonder if there isn't some other solution that doesn't depend on both $timeout (with a disabled $apply wrapping) and $evalAsync.

Comment: should i add answer?

Comment: @pankajparkar Let me do some more testing. I'll let you know if it's 100% functional.

Comment: This is still unresolved -- it doesn't work 100% of the time with either $evalAsync or $applyAsync.

Comment: now what is the issue?

Comment: I'm still having the same issue. The first animation on site load occasionally fails -- and so do animations when switching directions from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue a couple months ago.

I was forced to implement a solution that felt distinctly less "Angular", but works 100% of the time.

Long story short, I ended up adding and removing the classes manually instead of waiting for the next digest cycle.

For example:

```
var slide = angular.element(document.querySelector('#slide'));
slide.removeClass('right');
slide.addClass('left');
```

It was then trivial to trigger the appropriate state transitions.